# Windows 7 Activation with Bootcamp and VMWare

Tags: windows-7, boot-camp, vmware-fusion

I have windows 7(64) installation setup on a Boot Camp partition on my MacBook Pro 13".
I also access this partition through VMware hosted by OS X (snow leopard).

Every time I switch between VMware and Boot Camp windows says that it needs to be re-activated because of hardware or driver changes.

I've tried wmware KB [KB 1003426](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004917) to no avail.
Edo

Thanks,

Jason

Edit,

I am using the most recent VMware and tools.

I've tried 
["KB 1004917"](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004917) as well. No Dice.

I'm considering re-installing at this point.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of VMware Fusion with the latest VMware tools?

Comment: What about this kb article? http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004917

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I actually tried 1004917 quite a while ago with the 2.5(?) version of VMware. Tried again though and it still won't work. :)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by changing the virtual machine to use two virtual processors, which matches the actual machine.

It seems that 1 vs 2 processors was enough to trip windows activation.

Comment: Also try changing the MAC address of the virtual network adapter to match your physical MAC address.

Answer (score 0):

If you ring microsoft and advise them of your configuration they will provide you with another activation key for the unactivated setup either boot camp or through vmware.